# Compare percentage of words or characters

Tags: c#

I have a of list of phrases. Each phrase can be a single word or a list of words.

I would like to compare a phrase with each of its sibling phrases and rank those which match the most. Character match or word match come to mind. However the list is quite dirty with commas and hyphens, non-closed brackets etc.

The ranking does not have to be terribly accurate. It is needed as a helper for content editors.

Example list:

```
Hello sir, how are you?
```

Top ranking siblings to this phase in this list

```
Hello madam, how are you?
How are you today?
Today, are you well?
```

Is there an existing function out there to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something very similar recently. Here's an adapted version of my method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRankedPhrases(IEnumerable<string> phrases, string testPhrase)
{
    return phrases
        .Select(p => new { Phrase = p, Intersection = p.Intersect(testPhrase) })
        .OrderByDescending(pi => pi.Intersection.Count())
        .Select(pi => pi.Phrase);
}
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your code file.

This compares each phrase in `phrases` with the test phrase. Those that have the most characters in common will float to the top of the list.

Comment: Thank you for that code. Excellent starting point. I found in my case it listed way too generously. I going to adjust it to see if adding a rule that X of the words must match. Or, to split up the words and match characters against other words (oh ive gone tongue tied).

Comment: True, my method does no filtering whatsoever. It simply ranks from highest number of characters in common to least.